# How to wrap text around objects (like floating does) in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's say I have a `display: inline` container with some text children, and some `inline-block` children:

[image]

If I give the container the following CSS... (and change `inline-block` to `inline-flex`)

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
```

... then it treats the text element as an entire element of its own and wraps the whole thing, rather than breaking it up.

[image]

Is there a "flexbox" way of achieving this, or do I really have to fall back to display inline?

Comment: and if you want to achieve this why you want to rely on flex since it's working like you want ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's a good question. Our CSS is 90%+ flexbox, so I'm just trying to be consistent if I can. If it isn't possible, that's fine. I'd just like to do it the flexbox way if I can.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once you create a flex container (`display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`), all in-flow children become flex items.

Flex items are, by definition, "blockified", which means they are block-level boxes ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)).

Text elements represent inline-level boxes ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-boxes)).

Therefore, you cannot make flex items wrap in the same way as text (or floats).

Comment: I assumed this was the case, just wanted to ask the question here to confirm. Appreciate the explanation.