# Flexbox multi-column wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to create a two column format where the right column has two rows.  Within each row contents can wrap.

[image: Not wrapped]
[image: Wrapped]

What I'd really like is the lower row to appear directly below the content on the left.  Of course my existing html can't behave like that because the two column format restricts content on the right from wrapping over to the left.  Is there some other approach I can take with the html structure to allow this behavior or is this something I just can't do with flexbox, and look to float instead?

```html
<div id="container" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
   <div id="badge" style="border:solid red; display:flex; flex-direction:row;align-self: flex-start">
      <div id="icon">ICON</div>
      <div id="title" style="flex-direction:column;">
         <div>TTTTTT</div>
         <div>TTTTT2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="mnu" style="flex-direction:column;border:solid pink; ">
      <div id="row1" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap; border:solid blue; ">
          <div>R1AR1AR1AR1AR1A</div>
          <div>R1BR1BR1BR1BR1B</div>
      </div>
      <div id="row1" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap; border:solid green; ">
          <div>R2AR2AR2AR2AR2A</div>
          <div>R2BR2BR2BR2BR2B</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: *"What I'd really like is the lower row to appear directly below the content on the right."*.. Did you mean "left"?

Comment: @Michael_B - absolutely I did.  Sorry!

Comment: Then here's a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48253934/3597276